Salesforce sending unwanted emails when queue is assigned
I'm a relatively new salesforce admin, so bear with me here. I'm currently having an issues where

whenever a case comes in via email-to-case and is assigned to a queue other than the default queue (Either by Flow or by Case Assignment Rules), it is blasting an email notification to all members of the queue.

For my use case, this is unwanted behavior.
In the tested Flow, there was no email action, and the only flow with an email action uses a specific template, so I know that's not the cause.
I tried using case assignments, with email template blank,

No queues have the 'Send Email To Members' Option checked,
Notify case owners on new emails is not checked in email-to-case,
Notify Case Owners when Case Ownership Changes is not selected in support settings.

When manually changing the case owner to a different queue, the behavior is as expected, and salesforce only notifies users if the box is ticked to do so.
I'm kind of at my wits end here digging through the mountain of redundant options, and am wondering if I missed something. It doesn't help that i'm coming in after the implementation was set up by a third party

It could be custom automation doing it.  Have you checked workflow rules, process builders, other flows, and Apex triggers?  You may need to do brute-force testing in a sandbox by disabling off case-related automation items one-by-one and keep submitting cases until the emails stop.

We have no workflow rules, process builders, and i've gone through all the flows. The only flow I have with an email action doesn't trigger under the conditions of the problematic cases. As for Apex, we have a few that were put in place by the third party, but I am very much still learning and apex scares me so I don't even know where to start there. I was hoping to avoid the brute force approach, but that may be my only option.

If the previous consultant left no documentation and you can't speak to them, then unfortunately you have a hard road ahead.  Remember that in a sandbox you can disable an Apex trigger by going to Setup > Apex Triggers and editing it to uncheck "Is Active".  Also you can disable case assignment rules in the sandbox to simplify troubleshooting.
